# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager must be specified

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationFilter' defined in file [mypath\security\filter\AuthenticationFilter.class]: authenticationManager must be specified
>
> .
>
> .
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager must be specified

I started getting this error after solving a circular dependency error I was having, now for some reason my authenticationManager bean is null in my AuthenticationFilter

(which makes me think I didn't really solve it the program just breaks earlier now)

My Security Config:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter;

    /***
     * This method is used to configure the security filter chain
     * @param http
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/user/login");

        http
                .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable)) //h2-console fix
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(c -> c.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(c -> c
                        .requestMatchers("/user/login", "/user/register", "/h2-console", "/h2-console/*").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .addFilterBefore(new ExceptionHandlerFilter(), AuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilter(authenticationFilter);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

then my AuthenticationFilter

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        try{
            User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), User.class);
            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
    }

}
```

My CustomAuthenticationManager

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        User user = userService.getUser(authentication.getName());
        if(!userService.validatePassword(authentication.getCredentials().toString(), user.getPassword())){
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid password");
        }
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials());
    }
}
```

and my UserServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private static BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Override
    public UserDto saveUser(UserDto userDto) {
        userDto.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
        return convertToDto(userRepository.save(convertToEntity(userDto)));
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(String email){
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        return unwrapUser(user);
    }

    public boolean validatePassword(String password, String encodedPassword){
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(password, encodedPassword);
    }

    static User unwrapUser(Optional<User> user) {
        if(user.isPresent()){
            return user.get();
        }
        else throw new EntityNotFoundException("User not found");
    }

    private UserDto convertToDto(User user) {
        return modelMapper.map(user, UserDto.class);
    }

    private User convertToEntity(UserDto userDto){
        return modelMapper.map(userDto, User.class);
    }
}
```

Is there still a circular dependency here that I'm missing?
If not what's causing the authenticationManager to be null in my AuthenticationFilter?

also as a sidenote, do you have any tips of how I can debug this type of error in the future?

Tried injecting the dependencies via constructors instead of @Autowired but same result
also tried change AuthenticationManager bean to the actual implementation but the error is the same

Answer (score 0):

This is not caused by a circular reference, but rather it's because you aren't satisfying the requirements of your filter's superclass.

Your class extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`
which extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.  AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter implements the interface, `InitializingBean` which contains the method `afterPropertiesSet`.  In this method, you'll see that it checks that the authenticationManager is being set.  Since you aren't setting it, the assertion fails.

Here are two ways to solve this:

The easiest is to drop your Autowired annotation from the AuthenticationManager and set it in the constructor, calling super along the way.

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

  private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    super(authenticationManager);
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
  }
}
```

The other way is just as simple: Leave your AuthenticationFilter just the way you have it, but add the implementation of `setAuthenticationManager` to it.

```
@Override
@Autowired
public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

Either of these should resolve your issue.